# How to retrieve a "Run" tab in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

This might be a very stupid question, but I closed a tab of a "Run" tool window (the one you normally access with `Alt+4`) and can't find a way to get back to it.

I closed the tab with my app still running. Now, when I try to run my app again, I get "port XXXX is already in use".

What's the catch?

Comment: I terminated the app process using task manager and everything is ok for now.  Not sure if there's a "webstorm" way to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You go to the top bar menu, click the **Run** tab, and select **Show Running List**. This will pop up a list of all your currently running process and you can select the process you want to view from there.

More info can be found in the [WebStorm documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/viewing-running-processes.html)

Comment: I think I have an old version, because I can't find "show running list"

Comment: @Emilio, I'm running v2017.2. Try updating if you can and see if my solution works for you.